# I can't find where android.hardware.camera2.full came from

Tags: android, google-play, android-camera2

I'm trying to send an app to google play store, but it says that I have android.hardware.camera2.full and shows my app to 0 devices. I can't find where it came from (it's not in my manifest).

There is a way to "Bypass" these filter verifications?

Edit: here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="myapp.android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />


    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:exported="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/ZendeskLightTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

... Below here only activities and meta-datas

Comment: can you share your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: sure, i will update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

That comes from a third-party lib, I found it using ctrl+shift+f in full-scope mode.

Thanks!